# C# Compact Framework - File manipulation from two different programs

Tags: c#, file-io, .net-3.5, synchronization, compact-framework

**Description of issue**
I am using the .NET v3.5 Compact Framework to develop an application in C# for a mobile device. I currently have two programs that are used by the user to read or write data to (or from) and XML file. The issue is when I attempt to open the file from either of the two programs, then try to manipulate the file using the other program.

**What is going on?**
The XML file is being read and parsed by both programs. At that point, they become two separate entities in memory. The two sets of data are both changed at some point within the programs' running. Program #1 saves the changes. Program #2 also saves the changes, but will not have Program #1's changes.

**What should I do? Any suggestions???**
I need assistance in how to tackle this issue. Should I combine the two programs into the same solution? How should I approach having two separate programs manipulating the same file and updating each others data?

Comment: So you want to share data between two programs? Does one program's information affect what the other program does?

Comment: @lucrativelucas Yes, it does. They both pull information from the same file, and when one value changes for (example)property a, i want the program to save property a and cause the other program to update the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) use a seprate lock file as long as one process accesses the file for writing
b) use a new process that is the only interfaces the xml. Use some interprocess technique to manage the data of the xml (ie using sockets).
c) go away from using xml for the data and use a multiuser and transaction able database system like SQLite.

I would go with c)

Comment: The unfortunate reason I cannot use option 'C' is because very few of the users of the program will have no access to an internet connection. I do like option 'B' though and feel this answer has quite a lot more depth. Thank you.

Comment: Using SQLite does not need an internet connection. SQLite is a very small SQL file only databse system.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the file periodically (either when your application gets input focus, or on a timer, or immediately prior to overwriting the file) to see if the contents have changed.  If so, the program will need to reload the file and merge changes with the active entity in memory.  Conflicts may be possible (i.e. another program has changed part of an entity which has also been changed by your program), so you'll need to check for those and take the appropriate action, whether that's warning the user or just allowing the more recent change to apply.

The best way to detect changes will depend on how your data is structured and whether elements of your XML file can be uniquely identified.  Unfortunately it may not be a simple task if you haven't already written comparison code.

Comment: I appreciate your help and guidance. Thank you.